# Changing colour of two different list item content elements

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I have an `li` navigation with dividers created using the code shown below. I'd like to have two of these | elements but different colours, is it possible to define different colours for both?

```
#navigation li:before {
    content: "|";
    color: #800836;
}
```

I'd like another but with `#F2659A` and right next to the existing.

Here is the live url to see how things look right now:
http://www.jordancharters.co.uk/nakedradish/

Comment: Give unique id to all li elements , as you already have i guess, then to achieve different colors , try giving  different class names to have different colors.

Comment: Can you make a quick JSFiddle to give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: OP wants two Pipe characters `|` colored differently in the same `li:before` content.

Comment: Here is a JSFIDDLE with an attempt but too much of a gap. http://jsfiddle.net/8KZU2/

Comment: Could I just create an image of the 'pipe' and use that as the content:"" ?

Comment: I just tried using background image instead of content:"" using an image of the 'pipe' but it doesn't show up on the navbar. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try :nth-child to select every odd (for example) `<li>` in your `<ul>`, and then add the other color :after it.

```
#navigation li:nth-child(odd):after {
   color: #F2659A;
}
```

**UPD.**

```
content: "";
color: #800836; /* Dont need anymore */
box-shadow: 2px 0 0 0 #800836;
border-left: 2px solid #F2659A;
```

[image: Please take a look at the screenshot: is that what you need?]

Comment: Oh, just understood that you want "two Pipe characters | colored differently in the same li:before content."

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an option for you, but you can use the `:after` pseudo-element, as you use the `:before`, like this:

```
#navigation li:before {
  content: "|";
  color: #800836;
}

#navigation li:after {
  content: "|";
  color: #F2659A;
}
```

I cannot think of any other way to make it have two different colors without actual HTML, using actual pipes `|`. And we all know that HTML is not allowed in the `content` property.

**EDIT:** You can use `border: 1px solid #F2659A;` though, and the effect will be similar. Just make sure you use it for the `#navigation li a` element and then you can manipulate spacing (with margins and paddings).

Comment: This happens when i'm doing your example. Too much of a gap: http://jsfiddle.net/8KZU2/

Comment: Thinking about it, you can also add a `border`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous examples the adjustments are pretty simple if using two pseudo-elements.

[**CODEPEN EXAMPLE**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/IJusA)

CSS Extract :

```
li {
  height:40px;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

li:before,
li:after {
  position:absolute;
  vertical-align:middle;
  content:"|";
  left:100%;
  top:8px; /* eyeballed it */
  height:40px;
}

li:before {
  color: #800836;
}

li:after {
  color:#F2659A;
  margin-left:8px; /* change this to adjust gap */
}
```